# AS3 - add different event listeners to children or one to the parent?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, mobile, air, addeventlistener

I have a MC (a button bar) with 4 buttons. is it more efficient to add separate event listeners to each button or to add a single event listener to the parent and use e.target.name to detect which one was clicked? Thanks!

Comment: The latter, but you'd have to have a lot of listeners to make it a real difference in performance

Comment: For a click event, you could hundred of thousand items each with it's own click listener and wouldn't matter.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Events are costly, and for high performance applications with numerous event handlers you should [consider using callbacks instead of the event model](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a6d20da321260fed8a52-8000.html).

> The ActionScript 3.0 event model is based on the concept of object
>   dispatching. The event model is object-oriented and optimized for code
>   reuse. The dispatchEvent() method loops through the list of listeners
>   and calls the event handler method on each registered object. However,
>   one of the drawbacks of the event model is that you are likely to
>   create many objects over the lifetime of your application.
>
> Using the native event model can be slower and consume more memory
>   than using a traditional callback function. Event objects must be
>   created and allocated in memory, which creates a performance slowdown.
>   For example, when listening to the Event.ENTER_FRAME event, a new
>   event object is created on each frame for the event handler.
>   Performance can be especially slow for display objects, due to the
>   capture and bubbling phases, which can be expensive if the display
>   list is complex.

Likewise, [numerous mouse enabled interactive objects are cpu-intensive](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c36cfb8137124318eebc6-8000.html).

> When using an interactive object, such as a MovieClip or Sprite
>   object, the runtime executes native code to detect and handle mouse
>   interactions. Detecting mouse interaction can be CPU-intensive when
>   many interactive objects are shown onscreen, especially if they
>   overlap.
>
> When possible, consider disabling mouse interaction, which helps your
>   application to use less CPU processing, and as a result, reduce
>   battery usage on mobile devices.

From practical experience in animation, I can call several thousand callbacks versus a limited number of handlers per frame.

Per your example, the component architecture enables events to bubble up to the parent control; therefore, it's a better design pattern for the button bar to capture events.

Depending on how tightly coupled the buttons are to the button bar, a `switch` block of names / instances makes sense unless you are dispatching custom events abstracting button controls from the button bar control.

Answer (score 0):

This is you can use.

```
addChild("YourButtonName").addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

private function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    "Your mouse click Action is Here"
}
```